# Redefining styles of react components using CSS Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, модули

Всем привет! Не удается переопределить стиль компонента. Использую стилизации с помощью CSS Modules. Внутри компонента заданы базовые стили. Компонент имеет свойство className, добавляющее класс компоненту.

Класс, передаваемый через пропсы не переопределяет базовый стиль, почему-то :(

### **Компонент**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Chip.module.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import Icon from '../../Icon/Icon';

export interface IChipProps {
  className?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  title?: string;
}
export const Chip = (props: IChipProps) => {
  const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

  return (
    <div className={cx(styles.container, props?.className)}>
      <span>{props.title}</span>
      <Icon className={styles.icon} attrs={{ src: '/icons/transferHistory/close.svg' }} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### **Добавление класса**

```
<div className={styles.filterChips}>
        <Chip className={styles.filterChip} title="Feb 2020" />
        <Chip className={styles.filterChip} title="Min 2 Max 100 USD" />
        <Chip className={styles.filterChip} title="2 Addresses" />
        <Chip className={styles.filterChip} title="3 Accounts" />
        <Chip className={styles.filterChipClear} title="Clear all filter" />
      </div>
```

### Результате в dev tools

[image: Result]

**Спасибо за внимание**

Comment: Вопросы здесь принято задавать на русском языке, и текстом/кодом (не картинками). Советую исправить (отредактировать) вопрос поскорее, пока не набрались голоса за его закрытие... закрытие не окончательное (можно переоткрыть), просто будет быстрее сразу пофиксить вопрос, чтобы не ждать голосования.

Comment: убери все лишнее(оставь минимально нерабочий пример) и еше добавь (имя).module.scss(css) файл сюда